# How to download firefox installation for linux - oracle linux 6.10

Tags: linux, firefox, installation, oracle-linux

I'm searching to download firefox for linux for some test because my server didn't have internet connection.

I go to this link and click "Download now" https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/linux/

But what I got is `Firefox Installer.exe`? What on earth does linux now run exe? Didn't firefox devs know how to distinguish windows and linux?

And I even try going to custom link to change OS to linux, but what I got is the same .exe file https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/custom-installation-firefox-on-windows#firefox:linux:fx107

So how to download firefox installation package for linux (oracle linux 6.10)?

[image]

[image: 2]

[image]

Comment: If you're downloading from Windows it may - it shouldn't but it may - default to the Windows installer. You may want to select "Download in another language or for another operating system" instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you, I already done that with no help. You may want to remove blocking image from superuser and view my attachment images first : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download linux versions from here:

> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release

[image]

once downloaded transfer the downloaded file to the server,

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads>scp "firefox-106.0.2.tar.bz2" root@192.168.17.47:/opt/
root@192.168.17.47's password:
firefox-106.0.2.tar.bz2                100%  342KB   3.2MB/s   00:00
```

take ssh session & extract tar

```
[root@somehost opt]# ll
total 76880
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 78717878 Oct 28 15:16 firefox-106.0.2.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     4096 Oct 17 16:58 rh
[root@somehost opt]# pwd
/opt
[root@somehost opt]# tar -xjvf firefox-106.0.2.tar.bz2
```

change current directory to firefox

```
cd firefox
```

you will find firefox here

```
./firefox
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).